# Null return from C# application settings file

Tags: c#, null, settings, application-settings, configurationmanager

I am attempting to use this code:

```
 String MainDB = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MainDB"];
 MessageBox.Show(MainDB);
 String MailInfo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailInfo"];
 MessageBox.Show(MailInfo);
 String HousingIndexLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HousingIndex"];
 MessageBox.Show(HousingIndexLocation);
```

to access values generated by this screen:

[image]

Everytime the values are returned null.

what am I missing in my implementation of these settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
String MainDB = Properties.Settings.Default.MainDB;
MessageBox.Show(MainDB);
String MailInfo = Properties.Settings.Default.MailInfo;
MessageBox.Show(MailInfo);
String HousingIndexLocation = Properties.Settings.Default.HousingIndex;
MessageBox.Show(HousingIndexLocation);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're getting an error because ConfigurationManager is not the proper way to access properties stored in those files. Take a look at:

[Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Long story short, you access the settings in the Settings file using the Properties namespace:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MainDB;
// And so on...
```